# Find the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}}$

Tags: limits

Find the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{n}}}$$. Remark:there are n times square root within $n$.

Comment: Following the link above, it looks like (albeit the sequence is convergent) no closed-form expression is known for its limit: http://oeis.org/A072449/internal